# Find recent object changes in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've **added** and **modified** several (new and existing resp.) **tables** and **stored procs**, for a particular **database** and **server**, in **last 3 months**.

I was thinking if there's any SQL query by which I can determine all those changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Query the `sys.objects` table to find the objects that changed and filter by `modify_date` and `type`; U = User table, P = Stored procedure.

```
select * 
from sys.objects 
where (type = 'U' or type = 'P') 
  and modify_date > dateadd(m, -3, getdate())
```

This approach will tell you what objects have changed, but not the specific changes.

Comment: tjhazel, thnks. But results are too many and inlcudes other developer changes as well. Is there a way where I could filter the search based on the "logged_in user" who actually modified the mentioned change.

Comment: Needed this, thank you. If possibly, it would be lovely to include the related database name also. I've joined sys.schemas and gathered the schema.name for better info.

Answer (score 13):

Hi you can get the changed/modified db object details with this query

```
select name,create_date,modify_date
from sys.procedures
order by modify_date desc
```

Thanks

Answer (score -5):

I don't think you're going to be able to find what you're looking for.  SQL Server just doesn't track that information out of the box.

To handle this in the future, you can use some kind of source control (redgate, for one: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control),

or you can set up a DDL trigger (one such technique is described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33541/how-to-keep-history-of-sql-server-stored-procedure-revisions/33544#33544).

Comment: SQL Server *does* track modified date as shown in other answers.  3rd party software is not needed for this.

Comment: why was this the accepted answer? The answer below specifically answers this question

Comment: I'm surprised by all the negativity toward this answer. The other answers do NOT "specifically answer this question": neither of the two current other answers list WHAT changes were made to a database (tables, cols, etc.) or what SPs have changed (and what the changes were), which was the original request. Perhaps some feel that it's enough that they name what table or SP HAD changes, but even that's only a partial answer.